# Test the generation of an OAuth token in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, oauth

I'm writing a Ruby program that needs to interact with github via the API, so I'm using the github_api gem and generating an OAuth token. My code looks like so:

```rb
class TokenSetup
  def initialize(user, password)
    @user = user
    @password = password
  end

  def generate_oauth_token
    github = Github.new basic_auth: "#{@user}:#{@password}"
    token = github.oauth.create scopes: ["repo","delete_repo"], note: 'oauth token'
    puts "Your OAuth token is: #{token.token}"
  end
end
```

I'm somewhat new to Ruby, so still learning what some of the standards are. My question is, is it practical, or even advisable to test via rspec that the `generate_oauth_token` method actually generates a token? It doesn't seem so, since you need to provide an actual username and password. So I could create a test user on our github instance, but I'm not sure if this is something you would even test normally in rspec? I'm trying to make sure I have good test coverage for my code, so I'd like to include a test for this if that's the standard, or if there's a practical way to go about it without sticking a password in there. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

just saw your question. Two part of my understanding about your test process:

- Better cut off the dependency. There is no need to generate a token, and even unnecessary to make the HTTP request everytime you run your spec. Mocks and stubs help you test the behaviour, and to stub the web request, you may make use of [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) and [vcr](https://github.com/vcr/vcr).
- Get clear the intention of your spec. It's a little confusing about your `generate_oauth_token` method, that it creates an oauth token of the `delete_repo` operation.

  - If you want to test the `delete_repo` operatio, you may delete it once and stub it later.
  - If you want to test the token generation of the `github_api` gem, maybe you can just trust it, that's the third-party's responsibility.

Hope this can help.